# Display dropdown values below images

Tags: html, css

**1**) Text , Dropdowns & images are displaying like below image [ **4 rows** - 1+1+1+1 ] :

[image]

---

**2**) But **we need to display like below image** [ **3 rows** - 2+1+1 ]

[image]

**3**) I tried below code , now its displaying like below image [ **2 rows** - 2+2 ]

```
.product-options dt, .product-options dd {
    width: 90px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

First row is fine, its displaying  **SIZE & MATBOARD** , now I need to display "`Frame style`" in 2nd row and "`Frame width`" in 3rd row.

[image]

Here is [Site link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/wall1.html)

```css
.required {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.product-options dd {
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
}
dd {
  display: block;
  -webkit-margin-start: 40px;
}
```

```html
<dd>
  <dt>
      <label class="required">
       <em>*size</em>
       </label>
    </dt>
</dd>
<dd>
  <div>
    <select name="options[325]" id="select_325" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
      <option value="4397" price="30">Mini ( 16.98″x12.00″ ) +Rs30.00</option>
      <option value="4398" price="40">Small ( 16.98″x12.00″ ) +Rs40.00</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</dd>
<dt>
       <label class="required">
       <em>*Frame style</em>
       </label>
    </dt>
<dd>
  <div>
    <select name="options[325]" id="select_325" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
      <option value="4397" price="30">Cherry</option>
      <option value="4398" price="40">Natural</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</dd>
<dt>
       <label class="required">
       <em>*Frame style Size</em>
       </label>
    </dt>
<dd>
  <div>
    <select name="options[325]" id="select_325" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
      <option value="4397" price="30">0.75</option>
      <option value="4398" price="40">1.25</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</dd>
<dt>
       <label class="required">
       <em>*Matboard</em>
       </label>
    </dt>
<dd>
  <div>
    <select name="options[325]" id="select_325" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
      <option value="4397" price="30">Black</option>
      <option value="4398" price="40">White</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</dd>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, if you have no influence on html you can do css hack

try

```
.product-options dt:nth-of-type(-n+2), .product-options dd:nth-of-type(-n+2) {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 90px;
    }
```

and remove `display: inline-block;` and `width` from other.

Comment: thanks, updated your code, but i cant see any changes in [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/wall1.html)

Comment: you need to do two things, firstly add code I added and then in your code - line 1105 remove display:inline-block; and width:90px;

Comment: Thanks,  yes its coming as i needed, can you please help me to display those 3 images little bigger as i posted sample image in question......

Comment: there will be few things to do, lets go to chat, please create one